# Prototypal Inheritance in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am learning NodeJS and learning prototypal inheritance.

Below is the code I am using for prototypal inheritance .

The issue I am facing is  :

The `meow, purr and hiss` methods do get called on `leopardObj`.

But , whenever I call below methods , inside those methods , `this.name` is always coming as undefined.

```
leopardObj.meow();
leopardObj.purr();
leopardObj.hiss();
```

Can anybody please help me as I am not able to understand why `this.name` is coming as undefined ?

```
function Cat(name){
    console.log("Inside Cat before = ",name);
    this.name = name
    console.log("Inside Cat after = ",this.name);
}
Cat.prototype.meow = () => {  
    console.log(this);
    console.log("Meow for !!",this.name);
}


function Lynx(name){
    console.log("Inside Lynx with name = ",name);
    Cat.call(this,name);
}
Lynx.prototype = Object.create(Cat.prototype);
Lynx.prototype.purr = () => {
    console.log("Purr for !! ",this.name);
}


function Leopard(name){
    console.log("Inside Leopard with name = ",name);
    Lynx.call(this,name);
}
Leopard.prototype = Object.create(Lynx.prototype);
Leopard.prototype.hiss = () => {
    console.log("Hiss for !! ",this.name);
}
const leopardObj = new Leopard("Sheryl");
leopardObj.meow();
leopardObj.purr();
leopardObj.hiss();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meow`, `purr` and `hiss` functions are [arrow functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp), so you have bind your context incorrectly. Change them to regular functions back and everything will work as expected:

```js
Leopard.prototype.hiss = function() {
    console.log("Hiss for !! ", this.name);
}
```